# How to make curve links and add tooltip on links at the same time?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want a force layout with curve links to represent a directed graph. Also, tooltip for both nodes and links are needed, too.
By referencing [Mike Bostock's example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4600693), the goal of curve links were achieved by using an array called "bilinks". However, after joining the new data set 'bilinks' for each link, all other attributes of links were lost, so that I couldn't show any information of a link in a tooltip.
Is it possible to join another data set for links?
The code about node and link is as below:

```
  var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);   

  var nodes = graph.nodes,
      nodeById = d3.map(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; }),
      links = graph.links,
      bilinks = [];  

  links.forEach(function(link) {
    var s = link.source = nodeById.get(link.source),
        t = link.target = nodeById.get(link.target),
        i = {}; 
    nodes.push(i);
    links.push({source: s, target: i}, {source: i, target: t});
    bilinks.push([s, i, t]); 
  });

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(bilinks)  // Data join: join bilinks to make curve links...
    .enter()
      .append("g")
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    //.on("mouseover", function(d) { ...
    // here I have no chance to get original link attributes...
    ; 

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")  
    .data(graph.nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
   );

   node.append("circle")      
      .attr("r", function(d){
          if(d.id == center_id){ return 15; }
          else{ return 5; }
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) { //Tooltips for nodes
       div.transition()
         .duration(200)
         .style("opacity", .9);
       div.html(d.id + "<br/>" + d.group)
         .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
         .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
       })
     .on("mouseout", function(d) {
       div.transition()
         .duration(500)
         .style("opacity", 0);
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply push the original object itself inside `bilinks`...

```
bilinks.push([s, i, t, link]);
```

...which you can get as the fourth object in the datum array:

```
link.on("mouseover", function(d){
    console.log(d[3])
});
```

Here is Bostock's code with that change: http://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/6e849f33c828a9cac7037a4786f83766